# Android Support + Intellij Ultimate vs. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am developing with Android Studio so far. Now I realized that I am able to get a Intellij Ultimate license. I tried to figure out how to activate the 'ultimate' plugins in my Android Studio. But since Android Studio is based on the community edition this is not possible. Or is there any clue do to this?

The other way around: I use IntelliJ Ultimate and activate the plugin 'Android Support'. But then disadvantages appears like missing android studio specific buttons (sdk,avd,...) Is there any way to activate the Android Studio UI?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from using both ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Studio is a separate IDE. It's based on the Intellij platform but its a bit different.

There are plugins like [JRebel for Android](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-for-android/) that are not working (yet) in Idea Ultimate/Community and vice versa.

If you want to use Ultimate only features like database plugin or grails support or something else, you have to accept that not all Android Studio features are available.

You have to decide which feature set is more worth to you.

Comment: I suspect this answer. Nethertheless thank you. In my case I will go for android studio even I really really want to have the database plugin...

Comment: @Bolic This answer is absolutely right. If you really need both, use both. I personally choose ultimate for everything - except for android. Here I go with the previews an if they get too buggy I go switch back to ultimate